# How do I track 2 domains which point to the same host. 2nd domain points to a sub directory of the 1st site

Tags: google-analytics, hosting

This is my exact setup. I have a single web host. I have assigned a primary dns to that host. for instance www.primary.com points to the host. THe host allows 'addon domains'. An addon domain is in effect a subdirectory of the host, is accessible via www.secondary.com OR secondary.primary.com. I can ALSO access the content at www.secondary.com by typing in www.primary.com/secondary.com

I want to track each domain as a totally separate website, with no overlap in the visitors. (the sites for all intents and purpose are two completely separate site with nothing really linking the two)

I am absolutely confused as to what code to use where and how to customize it. So any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Either you use two different profiles with unique profile ID to track them (e.g. UA-123456789-1 for the www.primary.com and UA-123456789-2 for the www.secondary.com) and make sure each site only has one of the codes, or you can use filters based on domain/sub-domain/directory structure to do this (or to support it).

I would go with separate tracking codes, as it is by far the easier choice.

Example:

Site 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Site 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Be sure to create the profile for both.